# under the hood of expression evaluation using python debugger?

Tags: python, debugging, vscode-debugger

I wrote an expression in python which first evaluated correctly according to my input data.

```
def compare(data):
    return(["Senior" if age >= 55 & hand > 7 else "Open" for age, hand in data])
print(compare([[49, 5], [59, 8], [61, 5], [75, 11], [38, 6]]))
```

But when being tested with more produced data, I saw some errors in evaluation.
Doing some experiments, I found the error returns to operator precedence in expression.
In fact the true code is like this :

```
def compare(data):
    return(["Senior" if (age >= 55) & (hand > 7) else "Open" for age, hand in data])
```

I want to find a way using python debugger or another tool to hack an expression and see what is going on under the hood.
I am using VS Code for debugging. The only way I found was adding the expression to watch list. It evaluates the whole expression, but I want to know how python evaluates the expression and in which order executes the operators, just like the call stack using the debugger.

Comment: Can you clarify your question/be more specific? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: You should use `and` rather than `&`. `&` is for bit-wise logic, `and` is for boolean values.

Comment: I doubt you can do what you want, because Python compiled the code into byte code. It's easy to tell where statement boundaries are in the byte code, but individual expressions are not so easy to find.

Comment: to clarify my question : is there a way to trace the expression evaluation process(e.g. operator precedence) like the facility which debugger gives us to trace the call stack?